# Jetson nano i2c + dma

Tags: c++, ubuntu, i2c, dma, nvidia-jetson-nano

I use Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.9.253-tegra aarch64). What should I do if I want to work with i2c with dma? I need to transmit ~1MB of data every 1sec.

For non - dma transmitting I used smbus.h file from userspace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.